# jQuery version 1.11.3 .fadeOut() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm experiencing a strange issue while using the jQuery version 1.11.3 .fadeOut() method.

It's used to briefly display a percentage when the user changes the zoom level of an image using the mouse wheel. It more or less works as expected, except that moving the mouse seems to halt the fade in mid-progress until the mousemove event is complete. Examples depicting the relevant portions of my code are shown below.

```js
var value = 50;

$('#outer').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    //Do something
    console.log('bind outer');
});

$('#inner').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#number').replaceWith("<span id='number' class='number'>" + Math.round(value) +  "%</span>");
    $('#number').delay(300).fadeOut("slow");
        //Do something
        console.log(value);
    });
```

```css
#outer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#inner {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#number {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <span id="number">50</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Per the usual disclaimer that seems to be required these days, yes I have searched for answers. I also know that the jQuery .bind() method has been depreciated but it's not an issue because I may eventually port this code to pure JavaScript for better processing speed and and to eliminate the dependency on jQuery.

**Update:** It looks like this may be a browser issue. I tested it in Firefox 41.0, Chrome 45.0, Opera 32.0, Safari 5.1.7, and the issue seems to be specific to Firefox. I also tested it in Internet Explorer 8 (for XP users), but that is an entirely different animal.

Comment: i think that "MozMousePixelScroll" is used only on firefox , be carefull when using it !

Comment: Off-topic, and it's been a while since I had to say this, but ***`bind()` is not deprecated***.

Comment: i think youre experiencing the mouse wheel movement stopping your fadeOut because every time you move the mouse wheel, it triggers the bind event. what is your desired functionality?

Comment: MozMousePixelScroll is there to support older versions of Firefox, but I may remove it due to an issue causing the event to trigger twice in Firefox.

Comment: To be clear, the mouse wheel triggers the fadeOut() event, which works as expected if the mouse is held still. Moving the mouse (not the mouse wheel) is what causes it to halt mid-progress until the mousemove event is complete.

Comment: @David, are you doing anything fancy in your `mousemove` handler? Calls to `queue()`, maybe, or other animations on `#number`? Can you post the code of that handler if it's not overly long?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the code it triggers is rather long, probably too long to post, but all it does is performs basic calculations to shift the css background-position of an image relative to the outer div which acts as a container.